# Run a file path with different user name

Tags: windows, path, command-prompt

I'm coding a script that needs to load data from files, but my work computer and home computer have different user names:

C:\Users\Work\Dropbox\data.csv
C:\Users\Home\Dropbox\data.csv

I set up a cover in the windows command prompt before, where Windows will automatically look for "C:\Users\Home\Dropbox\data.csv" even if I specify "C:\Users\Work\Dropbox\data.csv". Unfortunately, I forgot how I did it. Now I have changed to a different work computer.

Anyway I can set up an alternative user name in the file path, so that I don't need to change the coding switch when I switch a pc. Thanks.